US International "Mac-like" keyboard layout
I'd like to only use a single keyboard layout because layout switching has been wonky for decades. In the Mac OS International US keyboard layout, they've seemlingly strived for reducing the risk of a user needing more keyboards. The most used non-US letters have been layered in, so for instance, Ø has been mapped to alt+O, å has been mapped to alt+a, etc.
Honestly it's kept me going back to Macs for work usage for more than 10 years since the business language is Danish here.
Is there a similar standard layout that can be fetched or easily set up? I switch between distros and WMs but mostly am on Fedora with Gnome.

You could try the US International keyboard layout, which supports most Western European languages. The non-ASCII characters are typed using a combination of AltGr (Right Alt) and letter keys. For example, you get an å character with the AltGr-w combination, and an ø with AltGr-l.
Most of the combinations are obvious; for instance AltGr-a results in an á character, AltGr-o gets you an ó. Unfortunately, since you can't have several mappings on the same keys, the combinations for å and ø are not the most logical. The layout is not the same as the one you have gotten used to on MacOS, which may also be a drawback.
I have used the US International layout for some years now, mostly because it is convenient for coding. I do write a lot of text in other languages than English, not just words here and there, and I got used to the odd combinations rather quickly.
For more information, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International

This is exactly what I was looking for and I feel dumb having overlooked this. Thank you very much, that picture is getting printed :-)
